# Is It Possible to Check Login Status of Facebook User without App Authentication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to check the login status of a facebook user on a website? If, the user has NOT authenticated the facebook app?

For example, visit the Yelp  website while logged into Facebook website. You will notice a bar at the bottom stating X number of your friends are using yelp. Join now...etc.

Yelp is displaying this data, and your friends data. Only if you have an active session in Facebook and NOT authenticated the Yelp Facebook app.

How does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although it's pretty hacky and there's no official support for it. Check this website for more technical details and a proof of concept: http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/detect-visitor-social-networks/

However, in the particular example that you give, Yelp is not accessing your Facebook data, they are only using a Facebook widget that pulls the data for display on a 3rd party website, however the website doesn't have access to any of that.